# Search/ filter bar in HTML, PHP

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to make a search/filter bar for my recipe website using HTML, PHP and its not working. I want to filter recipes based on user input in search bar. So far i made this code but when i type something in search bar i get this error:

- The requested URL was not found on this server.
- Apache/2.4.46 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.1j PHP/8.0.3 Server at localhost
  Port 80

[HTML code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EuBuT.png)
[PHP code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bNxDa.png)

```
<?php
session_start();
$db=new mysqli('localhost','root','','recepti') or die("Ni se mogoče 
povezati");

$search = $_POST['isci'];
$search = $db -> real_escape_string($search);

$sql = "SELECT ime_jedi FROM recept WHERE ime_jedi LIKE 
'%".$search."%'";
$result= $db->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) 
{
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
        {
            ?>
<div class="recept">
    <div class="recept-slika">
        <?= '<img src="data:image;base64,' .base64_encode($row['slika']).'">'?> </div>
    <div class="recept-podatki">
        <div class="recept-ime">
            <a href="recept.php?id=<?= $row['id_recepta'];?>">
                <?=  $row["ime_jedi"]?>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="recept-opis">
            <?=  $row["opis_jedi"] ?>
        </div>
        <div class="cas-kolicina">
            <div class="kolicina">
                <?= $row["količina"]?>
                    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="h-5 w-5" viewBox="0 0 20 20" fill="currentColor">
                        <path d="M9 6a3 3 0 11-6 0 3 3 0 016 0zM17 6a3 3 0 11-6 0 3 3 0 016 0zM12.93 17c.046-.327.07-.66.07-1a6.97 6.97 0 00-1.5-4.33A5 5 0 0119 16v1h-6.07zM6 11a5 5 0 015 5v1H1v-1a5 5 0 015-5z" /> </svg>
            </div>
            <div class="cas">
                <?=  $row["cas_priprave"]?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<?php
        }
}
```

Comment: Post code as text please, not images. We can't re-use the code in any answers etc if you only provide images. There's no reason not to just paste it.

Comment: P.s. I can see though that your button is outside the form so it won't submit anything unless you move it in the form or set the form ID in the correct attribute of the button

Comment: There is not submit button in form, put a submit button in form and you need to check the action attribute url if  that url is exist because requested url not found means that url does not exist actually and you need to put correct url in form action attribute

Comment: @ADyson i just added the code so you can take a closer look if you want.

Comment: @VirenderKumar I just changed the action atribute. I had action="get"  instead of method="get".. I changed that and now I get some other errors: Undefined array key "isci"  ... Undefined variable $mysqli

Comment: @naprekto Your code is not readable in question, try to use {} button to put code. Based on your given errors and from your images of code I am suggesting you to modify html
you are missing name attribute in input field in form
that should be name="isci"
and in php code
you need to replace $mysqli-> to $db->

Comment: @VirenderKumar works just fine now. Thanky you :)